# Wordpress cannot find function from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed a plugin **wp-fb-autoconnect**

I have activated it in the dasboard. Now I would to use a function from it.

**In my theme folder**, in one of my templates I want to add FB connect button

```
    if( function_exists(‘jfb_output_facebook_btn’) )
        {
            jfb_output_facebook_btn();
            jfb_output_facebook_init();
            jfb_output_facebook_callback();
        }
```

`function_exists(‘jfb_output_facebook_btn’)` returns false. The function is located in main.php in the plugin folder and i can see it. What's wrong? Please help.

UPDATE

The problem in general. A plugin has declared a function. I need to get access to that function from my theme folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`‘jfb_output_facebook_btn’` uses formatted quotes. Did you copy/paste that snippet from a blog? Try:

```
if( function_exists('jfb_output_facebook_btn') )
    {
        jfb_output_facebook_btn();
        jfb_output_facebook_init();
        jfb_output_facebook_callback();
    }
```

Be very careful of the kind of quotation marks you pass to PHP!

(BTW: Awesome user name. That game is brutal difficult.)

Comment: Thanks, the quotes seem to be non-real quotes at all.

Comment: No problem! Also: they're just stylized; often, blogs replace the less-interesting single-quotation mark with a set of opening and closing formatted quotes because they look better. The downside, however, is that they really don't jive with PHP.